# DICOM images display in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, digital

I am working with CT images that have the extension dcom . My problem is that when i store it using

```
dicomread()
```

I must use the '[]' in imshow() to view it correctly . What i need is to store it in a variable say x and when i view it i use

```
imshow(x)
```

only , so that it appears like this (original shape)
[image: CT image]

Not like this

[image: CT image]

In other words , i need to store the adjustment that is done by imshow(image,[]) on the image to a new image x for further processing.
I want to do this because when i use the image later it gives me wrong results due to the gray color that covers the image . 
Edit : Here is a further explanation to show my problem. I want to extract the 'contents' of the lungs with their intensity values . Due to the problem that i have mentioned above , i have used histogram equalization to obtain the below image : 
[image]

Next i have developed the lung mask :
[image]

Using this mask , i have tried to obtain the lung original values as i mentioned before , but due to the gray color that covers the image the lungs contents are disappeared :
[image]

even if i view this segmented image using imshow(segmentedimage,[]) , it shows it like this :

[image]

For anyone who need the file , here it is :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_mUVL9KNV3MTRk_kj5kiNOlEyGsrNr10/view?usp=sharing

Comment: CT has specific grey-values for specific tissue types (densities). Using histogram equalization, or normalizing like suggested below, destroys this relationship. You're better off using the known grey-values to extract the tissue of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that imshow(X,[]) does is scale the display range to the range of your data. In DCM images, it is common to have situations where the data range is only say, 12 bit, while the data type range is 16 bit (e.g. int16).

To fix this, all you need to do is rescale your data.

One way is to use the mat2gray function:

```
I = mat2gray(X);
imshow(I);
```

This will normalize your data to the range [0,1] as a double precision floating point result.